# Python import file from app

Tags: python, flask, python-import

I have a directory structure like:

```
.
└── app
    ├── urlregister.py
    ├── __init__.py
└── resource
    └── report
          ├── main.py
          ├── __init__.py
```

I need to import urlregister in file `main.py` .
Please help me and give me any code.

Regards,

Comment: Do you use Apache with mod_wsgi?

Comment: Did you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28527832/absolute-vs-relative-imports-in-python-2/28963444#28963444 ? I guess, it's a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use sys.path for this. Python by default, searches for the current directory for the files to be imported.

You can do something like this

```
import sys;
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/application/app(folder)')

import urlregister
```